# Visual Studio--Alter Variable While Debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to alter a variable while debugging?

Say for example I have this code:

```
    string x = "foo"; //would actually be a passed-in variable in the real world.

    var y = "X equals " + x;    

    ==>[BREAKPOINT] return x;
```

Is there a way to manually enter or otherwise change the value of "x" when I hit the break point?  Also , is it possible to "step back" in the code in the same way that you can press `F11` and step through it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are 2 ways to change a variable:

- Use the [Immediate window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Simply typing `x = "a new value"` will change it. Also, if you want to check the value of x use `?x`
- You can hover over the variable, and when the value displays in the quickwatch pop-up thing, just click on it an manually change it. (You can also add the variable to watch, or select quickwatch to change it).

If you would like to step to a different instruction, there are 2 ways to do that too:

- You can right-click on the line you want to go to and select '[Set next statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09yze4a9%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)'. This even works if you have hit an exception while debugging
- You can drag the yellow arrow that indicates the current instruction to wherever you need it